# Cuda out of Memory but I have no free space

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a gpu with 16gb available but cuda shows only 8 gb I assusmed it would be becoause its use gpu 0 so then I tried but that didnt work either what should I do

CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 384.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 8.00 GiB of which 0 bytes is free. Of the allocated memory 13.77 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 521.36 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)

I assusmed it would be becoause its use gpu 0 so then I tried but that didnt work either what should I do